# Equations and inequalities as parameters: proving that an equation holds.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have $x-y=3$ and $y\le1$ and $x\ge\frac12$.

I proved that $\sqrt{(2x-1)^2}+\sqrt{(2y-2)^2}=7$ and that $-\frac52\le y\le 1$ and $\frac12\le x\le4$.

How can I prove that $|x+y-5|+|x+y+2|=7$?

Comment: please see my answer @user114328

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok let us  consider following cases :

first side is  just  $-x-y+5$,second case is   $x+y+2$,so sum is $5+2=7$

to be more deeply,let us take such  situations

1. $y=1$

2.$x=4$

we have

$|x+y-5]+|x+y+2|=x+y-5+x+y+2=2*x+2*y-3=2*(x+y)-3
=2*(5)-3=7$

can you continue from this?

just consider this situation when $x<0$  then $|x|=-x$,else  if $x>=0$ then $|x|=x$.ok let us consider following case,when

$y=-5/2$   and $x=1$  ,we have that $-5/2+1-5<0$,that why we will have

$-x-y+5$,

for second we have  $-5/2+1+2>0$ ,

that why we have second as $x+y+2$,together is is still $7$

Comment: oups it is x-y=3 not x+y=3 :(((

Comment: Just a suggestion: to denote multiplication, you just need to juxtapose constants with variables, or when multiplying two constants, use $\cdot$ which is coded `\cdot`, and refrain from using the programmer's $*$.

Comment: i am new  in latex,thanks for suggestion

Comment: I understand! I was in the same position a while back, @dato. And I learned a lot just by these sorts of comments from other helpful users.

Comment: yes yes thanks,i will learn it,i know some commands,thanks for suggestion

Comment: my professor said that i should use $-\frac52\le y\le 1$ and $\frac12\le x\le4$ to come up with that resulkt

Comment: that what i  have done,you have to consider different case,i will  edit

Comment: see please updated version